# Arabluatex coloring

Tags: arabic, arabluatex

(I have tried to contact Robert Alessi, the Arabluatex package creator, but there seems to be something wrong with his email address, which used to be okay.)

In the example below, how do I make the long vowel alif red but not the diacritic mark on the letter "t"?

When I try `\arb{kit\arbcolor[red]{A}buN}` both the long vowel alif and the diacritic mark on the letter "t" is red.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write:

```latex
\begin{arab}
  \arb{kita\arbcolor[red]{"A}buN}
\end{arab}
```

(But what @salim-bou suggests also works.)

Answer (score 0):

How about `\arb[novoc]{k--.it.a\arbcolor[red]{A}b"uN}`?

**Complete MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\begin{document}

\Huge
    \arb[novoc]{k--.it.a\arbcolor[red]{A}b"uN}

\end{document}
```